# Pi Buster keyboard barcode scan not working without console, any way to spoof it?

Tags: python, console, keyboard, barcode

Can anyone help?
I have a Pi3b running Buster and Python3 with a USB barcode scanner attached. I have all of the code working utilising the keyboard input stream method and it works great from the IDE with a console open, but only with the console in focus. BUT that focus aspect is not the issue directly. I need to run this independent of the IDE but a direct launch does not open a console for the barcode input and so the application does not react, i.e. it behaves like it does in the IDE when the console is open but not in focus.

I am pretty sure I cannot spoof this by opening a console from Python as that is not supported as far as my research has shown so far, so does anyone know of a work around?

I appreciate I could probably do this with direct reads using something like 'evdev' library but as the code is all already written I was hoping for a quick fix rather than a complete rewrite! Also I would rather not use a 3rd party library if possible, and the keyboard stream method is both simple and avoids that.
Any thoughts?

Not sure it adds anything, as I think this is more of a input stream conceptual runtime environment issue than a code issue, but as a newbie I could be wrong :) but if it helps, below is sample code as requested

```py
def barcodewait (): # called as sub process to multitask reads
    while (1):
     # Kb stream barcode, CLI must be in focus else UPC goes elsewhere!        
        UPC = ""
        try:
            UPC = input()
        except EOFError: 
            print ("Error: No input or End Of File is reached")
        if UPC != "": barcode (UPC)
```

Not sure if it is relevant but....
Unless run in the IDE (which opens a console window and the scan appears there), the code is playing OMX full screen with no application window open. Could this mean there is nowhere for the keyboard stream (with the barcode) to go to as there is no in focus window?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.